# 12.04 Wireless Internet missing firmware

Tags: 12.04, wireless, firmware

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Compaq Pesario V2000, however, I am missing te appropriate firmware for wireless access. I am somewhat of a noob to Ubuntu so semi-detail instructions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?lang=eng&DwnldID=10138

this page provides the drivers for your specific wireless card I suppose.